# String gets added instead of concatenating

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to concatenate and display hours, minutes and seconds but they get added like integers instead of concatenating. What am I doing wrong?

```
var date = new Date();
  //return 
  console.log(
  date.getHours()<10 ? "0"+date.getHours() : date.getHours().toString() 
  + date.getMinutes()<10 ? "0"+date.getMinutes(): date.getMinutes().toString() 
  + date.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + date.getSeconds(): date.getSeconds().toString());
```

I get a number like 13 instead of the time like 012208

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var date = new Date();
  //return 
  console.log(
  (date.getHours()<10 ? "0"+date.getHours() : date.getHours().toString() )
  + (date.getMinutes()<10 ? "0"+date.getMinutes(): date.getMinutes().toString()) 
  + (date.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + date.getSeconds(): date.getSeconds().toString()));
```

here it is. check the brackets

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the precedence that you use in the ternary operators.

```
console.log((date.getHours()<10 ? "0"+date.getHours() : date.getHours().toString())+ (date.getMinutes()<10 ? "0"+date.getMinutes(): date.getMinutes().toString()) + (date.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + date.getSeconds(): date.getSeconds().toString()));
```

This would solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,you are not closing the `ternary` operator

```js
var date = new Date();
//return 

    var h = date.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + date.getHours() : date.getHours().toString();
    var min = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes().toString();
    var sec = date.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + date.getSeconds() : date.getSeconds().toString(); console.log(h +':'+ min +':'+ sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the parentheses:

```
console.log(
      (date.getHours() < 10 ? '0' + date.getHours().toString() : date.getHours().toString()) +
      (date.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + date.getMinutes().toString() : date.getMinutes().toString()) +
        (date.getSeconds() < 10 ? '0' + date.getSeconds().toString() : date.getSeconds().toString()) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your need to add parentheses around your conditionals. As it you currently have it, it is executing as if it were:

```js
function dateStr(date) {
  var hoursStr, minutesStr, secondsStr;
  
  if (date.getHours() < 10) {
  
      hoursStr = "0" + date.getHours();
    
  } else {
  
      if (date.getMinutes() < 10) {

          minutesStr = "0" + date.getMinutes();

      } else {

          if ( date.getSeconds() < 10) {

              secondsStr = "0" + date.getSeconds();

          } else {

              secondsStr = date.getSeconds().toString();

          }

          minutesStr = date.getMinutes().toString() + secondsStr;

      }

      hoursStr = date.getHours().toString() + minutesStr;
    
  } 
  
  return hoursStr;
}

var date = new Date();
// If the hours/minutes/seconds are 10 or more you will get what you want
date.setHours(10);
date.setMinutes(10);
date.setSeconds(10);

console.log(dateStr(date)); // => "101010"

// If the minutes are less than 10, no seconds show
date.setMinutes(5);
console.log(dateStr(date)); // => "1005"

// If the hours are less than 10, no minutes or seconds show
date.setHours(4);
console.log(dateStr(date)); // => "04"
```

By adding parentheses around your conditionals, you can correct the order of operations:

```js
var date = new Date();
console.log(
  (date.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + date.getHours() : date.getHours().toString()) +
  (date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMinutes(): date.getMinutes().toString()) +
  (date.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + date.getSeconds(): date.getSeconds().toString())
);
```